# Hindi font not working in webview but it work on web page

Tags: android, webview

I simply Call WebPage Through Url And on web Page i provide Facility to write Text in Hindi on Server/WebSite it working Fine But when i call in my Application It will not work....

```
try {
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 

    String language_url = "http://pratinidhi.in/DataInsert.aspx?requestfor=" + RequestId 
        + "&APPID=" + GlobalValue.AppId 
        + "&UPID=" + GlobalValue.User_Id;
    Log.i("String Url", "" + language_url);
    WebView(language_url);
} catch(Exception ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: what's your android version?

Comment: 4.4 kitkat version but i want to support in all version

Answer (score 0):

add this two line

```
webView.loadData(hindi_content, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, hindi_content, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```